# required_unless & required_without_all Laravel Array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```
'cycleForms.*.files.*.realisation_end_date' => [
    'required_unless:cycleForms.*.files.*.file,!=,Pilih File',
],
'cycleForms.*.files.*.file' => [
    'required_without_all:cycleForms.*.files.*.realisation_end_date',
    'different:Pilih File',
]
```

I want 
realisation_end_date validate when file is not equal 'Pilih File' (working)

and

file validate when realisation_end_date is not null and file is not equal 'Pilih File' (not working)

Comment: I change default value of file to be null, and just use require_with, it works perfectly